# IPython-Notebook 'DataFrame' object is not callable'

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, mask

I am trying to educate myself on Python, IPython notebook, and Data Science taking an online Data Science Course. The first issue, which I could not solve on my own, is that I am trying to use a mask to sort a spreadsheet. However, as you may see in the attached screenshots of a sample data frame and the according mask, I keep receiving the error that "TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable".

Your help is very much appreciated.
Thanks, -P

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W18Z.png)

[mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7bXG.png)

Comment: You need brackets [] instead of parentheses ().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use square brackets instead of (). [] is used for indexing.

`df[df.Total>0]` should work

Comment: Could you please upvote or accept the answer if it worked for you?